# JSOUP to display images in Image view using the URL

Tags: android, jsoup

How can i use JSOUP to display images in Image view using the URL. Any sample code is available for that. I searched but i couldn't find out.

Please help me with any link.

Thanks.

Comment: can anyone answer my question please. I am able to fetch text from JSOUP, I am unable to fetch image from JSOUP. Please guide me how can i do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to get the image tag?

Answer (score 3):

fir make the connection with provided link then you can get the image with

```
imagesRec = document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
```

then

```
String imgSrcUrl = img.attr("abs:src"); // imagePath
```

the you will use the Picasso lib for displaying the url as image in imageView

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgSrcUrl).into(logo);
```

and thats it

Answer (score 0):

you would have to parse the url of the image from the tag and then put into a string or similar. this string you can then use to load your image into an imageView.